# Columns change is making columns blank instead of changing

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a tab separated file where I need to change two columns using awk. The code I am using currently, removes all the columns that I actually intend to change and is leaving them blank, and pasting the rest of the line as it is.

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r line ; do
some code.. (to get the value of $some_var and $another_var)
echo "$line" | awk -v var1="$some_var" -v var2="$another_var" -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} { $1=$var1 } ; {if($2!="") $2=$var2 }; { print }' >> file.tsv
done < text.tsv

File content:
A    B         D
1         3    4

Intended output
H    I         D
6         3    4

Output I get:
               D
          3    4
```

What I actually want to do is, I have a tsv file with many rows, and I have to modify 2 columns in it. In the below example (which are dates formatted as `%Y%m%d`), I want to change `ColA` and `ColB` values, where `ColA` should get the value of `ColC`, and `ColB` should be equal to the duration between (original) `ColA` and `ColB + ColC`. which means, in first row below, the duration between `ColA` and `ColB` is 814 days. Now I calculate 814 days after `ColC` date, which is `date -d"20160201 + 814 days" +%Y%m%d`. I get `20180425`. This value I should place in `ColB`. So I perform all these calculations in the while loop and then use awk to replace the columns with the values. It works but its really slow as I have to process upto 5 millions of records.

```
Input file
ColA        ColB        ColC
20151207    20180228    20160201
20170616    20180630    20170612

Expected output
ColA        ColB        ColC
20160201    20180425    20160201
20170612    20180626    20170612
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to add a sample of the file, both current and intended state?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, Please mention 3 things in your post always, 1- Sample Input-file in CODE TAGS, 2- Sample Output with CODE TAGS, 3- What you have tried so far. Please post in your post all these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in `awk` are referenced with their name. You use a dollar sign (`$`) to refer to a field in an awk program, followed by the number of the field you want. So `$2` references the second field and `$var` references field `var` if and only if `var` is an integer number, in any other case `$var` will be an empty string.

So essentially, your code is good. All that needs to be done is replace `$var1` by just `var1` and the same for `var2`. I hope this helped.

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r line ; do 
  some code.. (to get the value of $some_var and $another_var)
  echo "$line" \
    | awk -v var1="$some_var" -v var2="$another_var" -F $'\t' \
         'BEGIN {OFS = FS}
          { $1=var1 }
          {if($2!="") $2=var2 }
          { print }' >> file.tsv
done < text.tsv
```

After your update, I believe the following `awk` script should replace your while loop :

```
awk -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS}
     (NR==1){print; next}
     ($2!=""){
       t1=mktime(substr($1,1,4)" "substr($1,5,2)" "substr($1,7,2)" 00 00 00");
       t2=mktime(substr($2,1,4)" "substr($2,5,2)" "substr($2,7,2)" 00 00 00");
       t3=mktime(substr($3,1,4)" "substr($3,5,2)" "substr($3,7,2)" 00 00 00");
       dt=t2-t1
       $2=strftime("%Y%m%d",t3 + dt)
     }
     {  $1=$3
       print
     }' text.tsv
```

The idea is that we replace all dates by  an integer number of seconds starting at a given epoch (this is done with `mktime` which accepts a string of the form `"YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]"` and then convert it back with `strftime`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Stupid thing is I know that point. For some reason it just slipped my mind this time :P . Spent hours trying to figure out what's wrong when I forgot about this simple thing.

Comment: @TejaswiN, if you could let your complete requirement know to us we could try to help to make this code efficient too, for example `awk` could read file by itself too, let us know on same.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thank you for your help. Yes, I am aware of that. In my script I need to Calculate values that I need to replace those columns with, and those values are different for each line. Thus I do the calculations on a line basis which is why I used the (while read line).

Comment: @TejaswiN I think that is exactly what RavinderSingh13 tried to explain. Awk is a record parser and processes 1 record at a time. The calculations you do in `some code` can for sure be moved in the `awk` line (unless other files are involved, then it is just tricky). Example: `awk -F $'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{ var1=do calc; var2=do cal}{$1=var1}($2!=""){$2=var2}1' text.tsv > file.tsv`.

Comment: @TejaswiN, yes if you could let us know sample Input_file and expected sample output then who knows if we could do all things in single `awk` itself, let us know if you  are ok wit it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have updated this question below it. Thank you for your help it would be great if there was a way to optimize this.

Comment: @TejaswiN The problem is the `date` command which makes it dreadfully slow and the constant rereading of the files.

Comment: @kvantour thank you I was not aware of that. But is there any alternate for this?

Comment: @kvantour This solution is so much faster, thanks for that.
There is just one catch though.. I get the error

    awk: cmd. line:5: (FILENAME=test.txt FNR=402) fatal: strftime: second argument less than 0 or too big for time_t

I think it could be because the duration could be a negative value sometimes. Open for other reasons why this could happen

Comment: probably t3 +t2 overflowed, i have added a small update that might fix it. But for a better understanding we should see line 402 of the file.

Comment: . The columns A,B,C are respectively..
20170215,(BLANK),20170215. 
So this is when ColB is blank. I just changed the line 

    $2=strftime("%Y%m%d",t3 + dt) 

to 

    {if($2!="") $2=strftime("%Y%m%d",t3 + dt)}

and then it worked. Its surprising how fast this is compared to bash calculations part.